# Packaging failure

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, electron, electron-builder

Operation process

1. download 'vscode' source code.
2. run 'yarn run gulp vscode-win32-x64'.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zSg5.png).
3. Report an error as shown：
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5yQV.jpg).

I was hoping someone could help explain the error.
Now I can't find a solution.

Comment: Don't post code, data or error messages as images. Post them as text. See [ask]

Comment: Downloading electron: [========] 100% ETA: 0.0  seconds
‘vscode-win32-x64’ errored
HTTPError: Response code 404(Not Found)